# Scientific American was once a great journal

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Richard Dawkins comments on an Scientific American article titled "Denial of Evolution Is a Form of White Supremacy" with "Scientific American was once a great journal."
> Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/RichardDawkins/status/1461716406182023179)

What does "Scientific American was once a great journal" mean? It seems to me to mean "Scientific American was once a great journal, but now it has degradated." I am not sure it is what Dawkins means here.

What does it mean?

Comment: That's exactly what it means; SciAm used to be held to be a respected source of good scientific information expressed in a way that a reasonably well-educated layman could understand without being an expert on the particular subject matter. Recently, there are opinions that it is no longer a consistently good source of good scientific information.

Comment: 'Degradated' is not a word in English.

Comment: degraded, but you mean: is no longer a good quality journal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the implication.  To paraphrase:

> Scientific American used to be a great journal.

This implies "it is not a great journal anymore".  I won't attempt to analyse *why* Dawkins believes this.

Comment: See also the famous Mitch Hedburg joke which plays on this implication: "I used to do drugs. I still do, but I used to, too."